413 Request Entity Too Large with ASP.NET and NGINX
I am sending a request to an asp.net that is working with nginx and i'm getting error 413 Request Entity Too Large. I change the options client_max_body_size to 450M but it gives me the same response.
The request body is nearly 40000 line in JSON format.
Do you have any idea what is going on?
location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 450M;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }


If the limit is set for nginx and it still fails, it sounds like it's another limit, at whatever you have behind the nginx. Depending on whether it's IIS or just Kestrel, both have their own way of increasing the limit.

The default value of kestrel's limit is 28.6MB. My request is 1.15MB, so i don't this is the problem. is there any other option in centos 9 that i look for?
